# patent number 3605913 Dust suppressor for rotary drills

Tags: patent-services, us3605913

I think my father is the inventor of patent number 3605913 Dust suppressor for rotary drills.. he passed away in 1985.. Id like to know more .. or how can I find more info ?

Answer (score 1):

You can look it up at google/patents. I put the patent number in the tag region of your question and that causes a link to come up in the right column here. From there you can download a pdf of the patent. If you want to know more there is a way to order the "file wrapper" from the USPTO or other companies that offer that service. It can get expensive depending on its length. A file wrapper contains copies of all of the back and forth between the applicant and the USPTO.

Answer (score 0):

It expired long ago and is in the public domain.